# Solution to differential equation is defined on all of $\mathbb R$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ and $g$ be real, continuous functions and $i,j > 0$ constants, with 
$$0 < g(x) \le i|x| + j$$ 
for every $x$ $\in \mathbb R$. 
Prove that 
$$y'=f(x)g(y)$$ $$y(x_0)=y_0$$ 
has a solution defined on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Which are the assumptions on $f,g$? Continuous? Differentiable?

Comment: Continuous - edited that. Thanks

Comment: Good; what did you try? I suggest you to try using the Peano's theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem). Then to extend the solution to $\mathbb R$ you shall use the sublinearity condition...

Comment: It's clear that this proves that there is a solution, but how does it show that one of the solutions is consequently defined on all of $\mathbb R$?